# Tally votes from an input file?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, file-io

I'm trying to use python to create a program that can tally votes using an input file.

Say the input file contains:

```
Abby 10 Bob 3
Abby 5 Cathy 7
Cathy 2
Bob 1
Abby 22
```

I would want the program to be able to tally the numbers linked to their key (the name of the candidate) and then output from highest voted for to least voted for.

So an example output of:

```
Abby 37
Cathy 9
Bob 4
```

I was told I could use a looping mechanism but I am unsure how to do this in python.

My attempt is here:

[image: screenshot of my code]

Comment: Can you please show your attempt at this? Have you gone over any lesson plans or tutorials for the items you have learned so far in Python to know how to write a loop?

Comment: yes I'll edit my question to show my attempt, I know how to write loops but am unsure how to use one in this situation.

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks for how to enter and format your code here.

Comment: Do not show an image of your code. Please copy paste the text in to the question and use the formatting tools to ensure it is formatted appropriately.

Comment: i edited the question with the proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `+` where you want `+=`:

```
if voteinfo[i] in candidates:
  candidates[voteinfo[i]] + int(voteinfo[i+1])
```

Should be:

```
if voteinfo[i] in candidates:
  candidates[voteinfo[i]] += int(voteinfo[i+1])
```